# How to stream a MySQL DB Dump from Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

A docker container made a huge crawl and now the disk space from the VM is almost full. So, I need a solution to export the sql data without exceeding the disk space.

I already found a solution how I can create a [MySQL dump in docker](https://medium.com/@tomsowerby/mysql-backup-and-restore-in-docker-fcc07137c757) but in this post you would create a sql file which could be too big.

I am connected to the VM via ssh and can use the docker-cli. Do you know any solutions how I could kind of stream the data to my PC?

Comment: Just an idea... I had seen a trick for this, on how to transfer a file by using `netcat`. Check the "send file" part of this [photo](https://twitter.com/b0rk/status/1059651145461723139/photo/1) by [Julia Evans](https://twitter.com/b0rk/).

Comment: can't you provide a network path as the target for the dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With docker: i have 2 projects deployed via docker-compose
docker ps shows 2 mysql containers running:  proj1-mysql-1 proj2-mysql-1
so i can directly:

```sh
docker exec -it proj1-mysql-1 mysqldump db_development |docker exec -i proj2-mysql-1 mysql db_development
```

With ssh you can do the same but run mysql via ssh